# Is there anything wrong with exending Activity in order to use runOnUIThread?

Tags: android, android-activity, extend, soundpool

I have a class defined like so: (I have pages of code, but I'm only posting the relevant parts for readability).

Now, there's nothing 'wrong' with it, per se and it works great, but someone told me a few days ago that it wasn't a good idea to extend 'Activity' on classes from which I am going to make objects (ie, classes that I will make instances of) - And I do make a MyGLRenderer object at some point in my code.

So my questions are:

**1)** Is it 'bad' to extend Activity?

**2)** If so, why?

**3)** If so, how can I use *runOnUIThread* to create my soundPool class?

*If* it's OK to do then I will leave it, but if it potentially could create big problems, I'd be grateful if someone could let me know of an alternative way to access it.

(my classes are separate files, not outer and inner classes and I need to create my SoundPool object in this class as have all of my initiallisations in this class).

**Code**

```
public class MyGLRenderer extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

//Various pieces of code

public void onSurfaceChanged(){

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           sound = new soundMan(curView.getContext()); 

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it 'bad' to extend Activity?

If it is not a real activity, started by `startActivity()`, then yes, it is 'bad'.

> If so, why?

Because lots of things will not work correctly. It is a minor miracle that `runOnUiThread()` works, and there's no assurance that it will continue to work in the future as `Activity` is modified. In fact, it's entirely possible that it will not work on some older devices, or ones where the manufacturer has tinkered with `Activity` in ways that work for real activities but will break for misuses like yours.

> If so, how can I use runOnUIThread to create my soundPool class?

You don't. Use other facilities, like calling `post()` on a `View` or `Handler`, to route work to be done on the main application thread.

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare - thanks for this, it's very informative, appreciate, it.  Strange, my main Activity doesn't have startActivity() in it!! Anyway could you please give an example of how to use your alternative (read: correct) methods for using runOnUIThread - your help is very much appreciate - thanks

Comment: @Zippy: "Strange, my main Activity doesn't have startActivity() in it" -- `startActivity()` is what somebody calls to display an activity. The home screen, for example, will call `startActivity()` to start up your "main Activity" when the user launches it. "Anyway could you please give an example of how to use your alternative" -- `post()` is a method. You call it on a `Handler` or a `View`, where `View` is the base class for all your widgets and containers. You pass `post()` the same sort of `Runnable` that you are using with `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: Gotya, I understand now, I've tried to look for an example of how this works (post() / runnable) but I can't seem to work it out, please could you edit your answer to show how I can implement this into my code? I tried but I just got 'cannot create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare' which is exactly why I need to create it on the UI thread.  Thank you.

Comment: @Zippy: Since you obviously have a `GLSurfaceView` somewhere, call `post()` on it.